# Recreating entire activity stack after the application is killed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my application I have a stack of the following activities:

```
A -> B -> C
```

Each activity has a broadcast receiver as an inner class, that registers with an `IntentFilter` at its `onCreate()`, and deregisters at `onDestroy()`.

This pattern works well on normal cases, but fails when the app is killed.
When the app is reopened after being killed, only the last activity (`C` in the example above) is reopened, and its broadcast receiver will be the only registered one. If I terminate the `C` activity, the `B` activity will then be recreated (passing via its `onCreate()`), and so on with the `A` activity.

Is it possible to re-create the whole activity stack, instead of the top-most activity, as soon as the app is reopened after being killed?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this might be extending the Application context, and registering your receivers there.  Then, no matter which activity is started, your application will register its IntentFilters.

Comment: I am already extending Application (although for other reasons), but my need here is to keep the broadcast receivers inside the activities, and invoking all the broadcast receivers in every activity.